# Is it possible to have @OneToOne relation between 2 objects but not having the child automatically persisted in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity-relationship

I'm using jpa persistance annotations. I have 2 objects, Order(parent) and Transaction(child). I want to be able to fetch my oder and get its transaction. The problem is I don't want my transaction to be automatically saved when I save my order. I need to do some special processing on it before I save it.

Is there a way to tell hybernate not to persist the child object but still fetch it when I retreive the order?

I tried something like this

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "commande_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

This didn't work. I keep getting this message:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

When I try to save the order object. The first time I save the order the transaction object contains some data but its not ready to be saved yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could make the relationship bidiretional and controlled by the transaction side.

Something like

```
class Order {
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="order", cascade={}, insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Transaction transaction;
}

class Transaction {
  @OneToOne(name = "order_fk")
  private Order order;
}
```

If you do it in this way, the the order.transaction shoud have no writing influence to the data base.
But even it it works, i belive it is a hack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ralfh. Finaly what I ended up doing is modifying the flow logic of my process so I was able to save the transaction at the same time as the order. In the end it made more sense this way.

Answer (score 1):

What if you detach the Transaction from the Session?

```
session.evict(transaction);
```

Not sure if that will work but just an idea.